# Разделить переменную на две части

Tags: winapi, c, файлы, c++

Имеется переменная `char * buff;` в нее загружен файл функцией `ReadFile`.
Как мне разделить `buff` на две части? А потом сохранить, потом загрузить и склеить обратно в один файл.

Comment: Объявить новый указатель
 
    char* buff2 = buff + n; //n(Размер первой части в sizeof(char))
 
или что эквивалентно 

    char* buff2 = &buff[n];

Comment: Следует начать с какого-нибудь букваря по С++. Такие вопросы там как раз в начале разбираются.

Answer (score 1):

Данный вопрос, как уже вам сказали, в самом деле рассматривается во всех "гайдах" по C\C++, поэтому сперва вам надо было бы изучить как следует СИ, а уже только потом в WinAPI лезть( раз уж вы его через СИ юзаете ).

**Ну, вот вариант на чистом C:**

```
    char * _buff = "**This-is-a-simple-string-buffer**";
    int N = 18;                                      // разделитель
    char * _fp_ = (char*) malloc(N);                 // 1 часть
    char * _sp_ = (char*) malloc(strlen(_buff)+1-N); // 2 часть
    memset(_fp_,0,N+1);
    memset(_sp_,0,strlen(_buff)-N+1)
    memcpy(_fp_,_buff,N);                            // 1 
    memcpy(_sp_,_buff+N,strlen(_buff)-N);            // 2
    printf("%s --- %s\n",_fp_,_sp_);
```

Comment: ZeroMemory - это чистейший Си, да.

Comment: @Flammable, да уж, спасибо, не обратил особого внимания, когда писал, что это "на чистом СИ". Поправлю.

Comment: @Francesco, вас за язык никто не тянул, сами начали про "чистый си" :)
И вообще, лучше не приводить никакого примера, чем такой. Топикстартер только начал вникать в эти С/С++, а вы его приучаете к плохому стилю и смешиванию STL с WINAPI на ровном месте.

Comment: Ггг, имел в виду stdlib. Пофиксил.

Comment: Ну даже если и так, то по-вашему использование одной лишь функции из стандартной библиотеки СИ( malloc ) есть смешивание stdlib с WinAPI? Кстати говоря, в коде не присутствует ни одной функции из WinAPI.

Comment: Одной? Их тут несколько больше. ZeroMemory вы уже заменили на memset, да.

Comment: @Francesco, а зачем 

1) записывать сначала нули, а потом поверх них копию подстроки?

2) выделять N байт и писать туда на 1 байт больше?

3) вызывать strlen() 2 раза?

И наконец, а что произойдет, если N > strlen(\_buff)?

Comment: Если, например, не сделать обнуление памяти, то там будет находиться мусор, который при дальнейшей работе портит исходную строку. А вот оптимизацией уже пускай займется ТС. Оптимизировать можно все и сколь угодно много раз, поэтому я оставлю код таким, какой он есть.

Comment: @Francesco, о каком мусоре Вы говорите?

Смотрите, Вы делаете malloc() и memset(). Записываете нули. Сразу затем Вы вызываете memcpy() и записываете содержимое первой части строки **поверх нулей**. 

Зачем надо было писать нули? **Абсолютно лишнее** действие. 

Теперь понятно?

--

А упорствовать в своих ошибках не стоит.